# changing the shape of a 4D ndarray in python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I am using this function to re-index a 4d matrix.

```
def insideout(ndimage):
    len_outrow = len(ndimage)
    len_outcol = len(ndimage[0])
    len_inrow = len(ndimage[0][0])
    len_incol = len(ndimage[0][0][0])

    reversed_image = np.empty((len_inrow,len_incol,len_outrow,len_outcol))
    for outrow in range(len_outrow):
        for outcol in range(len_outcol):
            for inrow in range(len_inrow):
                for incol in range(len_incol):     
                    #reverse the indices
                    reversed_image[inrow][incol][outrow][outcol]=image[outrow][outcol][inrow][incol]
    return reversed_image
```

This worked fine for a 326x326x43x25 matrix. It successfully changed the shape of the matrix into (43,25,236,236).

I applied some computations on the matrix which does not change its shape and now I want to revert it back using the same function.

However this time I receive the following error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
last) <ipython-input-18-da92ca90d937> in <module>
----> 1 insideout(reversed_image)

<ipython-input-17-4edf23c1ed04> in insideout(ndimage)
     17                 for incol in range(len_incol):
     18                     #reverse the indices
---> 19                     reversed_image[inrow][incol][outrow][outcol]=image[outrow][outcol][inrow][incol]
     20     return reversed_image

IndexError: index 25 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 25
```

I don't understand where the error is coming from! Why there is an index 25 (since I already used range() inside the for loop)?

The input matrix is a 4D ndarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your code,

```
reversed_image[inrow][incol][outrow][outcol]=image[outrow][outcol][inrow][incol]
```

you are not using `ndimage` but another variable that exist outside the function.
Instead it should be

```
reversed_image[inrow][incol][outrow][outcol]=ndimage[outrow][outcol][inrow][incol]
```

Comment: Oh my!.. Thank you ^^